# What's the way to create a collection of different custom components?

Tags: delphi, opengl, collections

hi to all In advance Sorry for my english.

I'm explain my problem. For an OpenGL library. I have a generic Shader component (TGLCustomGLSLShader). I'd like to make a Shader Library collection. At this time i can add TGLCustomGLSLShader in my collection. But i'd like also add descendant of TGLCustomGLSLShader. for Example : I create specific shader like TGLBumpMapShader, a TGLWaterShader  ect.... with differents custom properties in each and are not present in the base class. I'd like to add this new classes in my collection and view there custom properties at design-time. It is possible ?
How can make this ? Have you some links ? I tried to search with google, but i don't find any clues.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to implement this with full design-time and DFM support:

1. Have the common base class (`TGLCustomGLSLShader`) derive from `TCollectionItem`, and then create a `TOwnedCollection` published property in your main Library component to hold them.  Users will not be able to drop shaders on the Form at design-time, but the native collection editor should be able to delete/edit the shader objects normally. You can create a custom design-time editor that allows users to create instances of your shader classes, passing the `TOwnedCollection` object to their constructor.  You will also have to implement custom DFM streaming for the Library component so it will create instances of the appropriate shader classes  when loading a DFM, otherwise it will create `TGLCustomGLSLShader` objects instead of derived objects.
2. Have the common base class derive from `TComponent`, thus allowing users to drop shaders on the Form and configure their properties like normal components.  Then, in your Library component, create a `TOwnedCollection` published property, and define a custom `TCollectionItem` class for it that has a published `TGLCustomGLSLShader` property.  This will allow the user to use the native collection editor to add items and then manually link them to the desired shader components as needed.  While this requires more objects and more user setup, it is friendlier on the native design-time editors and DFMs, as it allows default behaviors to act normally and does not require any custom design-time editors to manage the objects.

Comment: Thanks Remy, if i understand i'll must create One Custom TCollectionItem for each shader component i have. Like TCustomShaderItem, TBumpShaderItem, TWaterShaderItem and Register items as classes in my collection.

Comment: If you go the 1st approach, then yes, as each `TGLCustomGLSLShader` would act as its own collection item directly. But if you go the 2nd approach, then no, because a single `TCollectionItem` class would be able to point to any external `TGLCustomGLSLShader` component. Personally, I would suggest the 2nd approach, it is easier to implement.

Comment: Hum, Thanks remy. The things i don't want to do is to put 100 Shader components on my form. So i'll take a look to 1st solution and i'll search some tutorials on this technique and do it if i can. Otherwise it's not necessary to have shaderlibrary because i can set and choose direcly shader in my 3D Objects.